# Making queries based on input via form and displaying the result

Tags: django, django-views

I have generated a form which takes an input from the user, I am making a query based on the input and storing the results of the query in a variable `data`.
 
I wish to render a page(display.html) which displays the data in variable `data`.
How shall I define the url to map to display.html?
Do I need to define a separate view for display.html? If yes, how can I pass the variable `data` to the new view?
What is the correct method to achieve this?
This is my views.py file, displayform function handles the form and its input

```
def displayform(request,user_pk):
    user=User.objects.get(id=user_pk)
    if request.user.is_active and request.user.id==user.id:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.POST:
                form=InpurDateForDisplay(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    dd=form.cleaned_data['dd']
                    mm=form.cleaned_data['mm']
                    yy=form.cleaned_data['yy']
                    data=user.link_set.filter(date=datetime.date(day=dd,month=mm,year=yy))
                    return render_to_response('app1/display.html',{'data':data,})
            else:
                form=InpurDateForDisplay()
            return render(request,'app1/displayform.html',{'form':form,})
    else:
        return render(request,'app1/error.html')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. A view only needs one URL. What exact problem do you have?

Comment: While writing the url for the output page(display.html), what view shall I map the url to?

Comment: I solved the issue, I was using a DateTimeField  field type and my query was supplying a DateField field type. I confused the error with url-mapping issue. Now I got your point, I don't need a different url for display.html, it is already rendered from inside a view in which the form is generated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a set of generic views for displaying time based content: [Generic date views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/).

If you are not making any changes to models you should use GET parameters to filter the results you are returning.

Something like:

```
def displayform(request, user_pk):
    user=User.objects.get(id=user_pk)
    if request.user.is_active and request.user.id==user.id:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            date = request.GET.get('date', None)
            links = user.link_set.all()
            if date:
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, <your date format>).date()
                links = links.filter(date=date)
            return render_to_response('app1/display.html',{'data':links,
                                          'form': InpurDateForDisplay()})

    else:
        return render(request,'app1/error.html')
```

Comment: I'll go through the generic date views once I get out of this mess. Thanks :)